# Is possible to figure out the source class of a serialized object?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I'm working with a proprietary software that store a serialized object in the database. I'm trying to recover the data inside this object the I don't know the source class of this object to deserialize it.
Is there a way to figure out the source class that was serialized? Some code that give the source class name.

I really appreciate any help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just deserialize it and call `getClass()`:

```
Object object = in.readObject();
System.out.println(object.getClass());
```